# Difference between <em> and <dfn>?

Tags: html, css

What is the main difference between <em> and <dfn>,as we use them ,both only italicize text.. and if <dfn> does something else then what it is? 
Also, why we use <dfn> with title attribute as we already have <abbr>?

Comment: Please search before you ask. There are plenty of resources (W3, MDN, etc) out there that explain this, or at least quite exactly what either element is for. If you are unsure about bits of the specs or external resources be sure to be specific in your question about why you're unclear.

Answer (score 5):

Neither *only italicize text*, that is just the default, graphical representation of their meaning applied by most browsers.

HTML is a *semantic* markup language, not a presentation one.

> The dfn element represents the defining instance of a term. The paragraph, description list group, or section that is the nearest ancestor of the dfn element must also contain the definition(s) for the term given by the dfn element

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-dfn-element

> The em element represents stress emphasis of its contents.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element